# send data from C# form to node server socket.io

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send data from a C# form which I have stored in a variable called `ClientMsg`. I am using `SocketIoClientDotNet` to communicate to the node server. I have the connection setup which is all fine but I am unable to send data from the form to my server.

Could someone tell me how to do this as I cant find anything online?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9FHC.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF3AF.png) [Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t11aT.png)

**Update** (added code):

```
private void socketManager()
    {
        var server = IO.Socket("http://localhost");
        server.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
        {
            UpdateStatus("Connected");
        });
        server.On(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, () =>
        {
            UpdateStatus("disconnected");
        });
        server.Emit("admin", ClientMsg);
    }
```

Button:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ClientMsg = txtSend.Text;
        if (ClientMsg.Length == 0)
        {
            txtSend.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            txtSend.Clear();
            lstMsgs.Items.Add("You:" + " " + ClientMsg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give us code snippets (not code as picture)? It's hard to try code without the possibility to copy/paste it into IDE or whatever.

Comment: @colidyre sorry about that new to all this! Added

Comment: I'm not sure I get your code, where are you sending data from your form?

Comment: @Haytam I am trying to send data from my textbox to the server

Comment: Oh I get it now. What you're doing now will not work as you're not actually sending anything when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you tell me the Type of your `server` variable? in socketManager

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by type of my server?

Comment: The Type of an object is like the name of its class, you hover over the variable and it says it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to send a message directly after connecting, using the `ClientMsg` variable which is null at first.
Even if you type something in your textbox, it'll stay null because in your button click event you're declaring a new `ClientMsg` which is local, so you're not working with the global one.

Here's how it should be:

```
// Save your connection globally so that you can
// access it in your button clicks etc...
Socket client;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeClient();
}

private void InitializeClient()
{
    client = IO.Socket("http://localhost");
    client.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
    {
        UpdateStatus("Connected");
    });
    client.On(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, () =>
    {
        UpdateStatus("disconnected");
    });
}

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String clientMsg = txtSend.Text;
    if (ClientMsg.Length == 0)
    {
        // No need to clear, its already empty
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Send the message here
        client.Emit("admin", clientMsg);
        lstMsgs.Items.Add("You:" + " " + clientMsg);
        txtSend.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Really appreciate it!